# How do the President's initial three decisions affect the story?

Tags: saints-row-iv

At the beginning of the game, the President makes three selections about supporting a humanitarian action, punching a politician, and hanging out with someone. What are the ramifications of choosing one option versus the other? What effect do the choices have on the game and its story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is curing cancer or ending world hunger. The second decision is punch a dickhead or punch a dick in the head. The third one is hanging out with someone.

As far as I see while playing it, these do not matter. They are just to make the intro of the boss that much more "Saintsy".

Answer (score 0):

I completed the story on PS3. I didn't see anything that seems to be an effect of any of those decisions. I did see a video of some of the people involved in making the game playing through a bit and they said it was very important. Maybe its BS or maybe I wouldn't know because I only played through one time and it wasn't an obvious result

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you choose to end world hunger, or to eradicate cancer, BOTH ACTUALLY HAPPEN in one scene of the game. The second time you escape the simulation there is no more world hunger, and there is no more cancer.
Punch a dickhead means you punch the guy in the dick. Punch a dick in the head means you punch him in the face.
Don't promise to go see the movie though. Probably not going to be able to keep that.

Comment: "The second time you escape the simulation there is no more world hunger, and there is no more cancer."
where do you see this?

Answer (score -2):

The only thing that seems to be affectin anything is the punching. depending on your choice, you either punch in the duck or the head in the game